# Automatically checking for NULL relationships with LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using LINQ to SQL to handle the database querying for an application I am working on.

For the purposes of this example, imagine I have some tables like so

```
- Company
- Product
- Item
- Order
```

and lets say a `Company` has 0 or more `Products`, a `Product` has 0 or more `Items`, and an `Item` has 0 or more `Orders`.

Now lets so I have obtained a list of `Orders`, something like:

```
IQueryable<Order> myOrders = GetMyOrders();
```

Now lets say I want to query the orders for a particular `Company.Name`, but have a situation where each table parent ID can be `NULL` (I know this doesn't seem logical with my example data but it is just an example)

Making the assumption that there are no `NULL` parent IDs I could do this:

```
var filteredOrders = myOrders.Where(x => x.Item.Product.Company.Name == "Company1");
```

This would work fine, however, because there could be `NULL` parent ID values, I need to check each parent object to ensure it is not `null` before querying the next parent (otherwise I will get an exception). So I do something like:

```
var filteredOrders = myOrders.Where(x => 
    x.Item != null &&
    x.Item.Product != null &&
    x.Item.Product.Company != null &&
    x.Item.Product.Company.Name == "Company1");
```

**So my question**: Is there a better way (in terms of readability and ease of coding) to do this than having to include all the null checks? Any null parents found along the way should result in exclusion from the resulting list.

Please no suggestions for preventing null parents, the database will not be changing (and is perfectly valid anyway)

Comment: Better as in more performant? I don't think so. I can't think of anyway you can rid yourself of all those `null` checks. Better as to prettier code? I'd go with Lonli-Lokli's suggestion.

Comment: @InBetween: Sorry, When I say better I meant more for readability. But keeping in mind my comment to Lonli-Lokli's post, where I mentioned the desired to ultimately have it run as an SQL query and not first return all results

Comment: Sounds like a perfect application for inner joins, which will eleminate all elements with null references. Join all tables and filter the result by company name. (But this won't be more readable)

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what happens if you have; var filteredOrders = myOrders.Where(x => "Company1" == x.Item.Product.Company.Name);

Comment: @MrMoose: Without checking, this will just give the same null exception if the parents don't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you can do

```
var filteredOrders = myOrders.Where(x => 
    x.Item?.Product?.Company?.Name == "Company1");
```

Comment: I am going to accept this answer, as the other answer is pretty much just a link-only answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I just got lucky by coming to this question 9 years later 

Answer (score 3):

there is known pattren (see Null object pattern). Also you can read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109026/Chained-null-checks-and-the-Maybe-monad)

Comment: I have had a read of that article and it was certainly interesting. However, because of my usage I am wondering if this would be appropriate for me. Assuming your suggestion is to create an extension method, I fear this will have a major performance hit for me in that I am using IQueryable and do not want to execute the query on all results. I am of course assuming I would have to do this (e.g work with a List<Order> instead) - maybe with this is mind I am left with having to do things the long way... any thoughts?

Comment: Then you should write your own implementation of linq-to-sql provider and combine those extension methods into sql queries like suggested above. Or you can just write those queries from scratch.